# how to access the nested data in firebase realtime database using PHP?

Tags: php, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and I am facing trouble in accessing the nested data(car_color,car_number,car_model,type)....

Can anyone help ??

```
<?php
include('dbcon.php');

      $ref_table='drivers';

      $fetchdata = $database->getReference($ref_table).child('car_details')->getValue();

      $i=1;
      if($fetchdata>0)
      {
            foreach($fetchdata as $key => $row)
            {
    ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?=$i++?></td>
              <td><?=$row['id']?></td>
              <td><?=$row['name']?></td>
              <td><?=$row['email']?></td>
              <td><?=$row['phone']?></td>
              <td><?=$row['car_details']?></td>
              <td><?=$row['car_number']?></td>
              <td><?=$row['car_color']?></td>
              <td><?=$row['type']?></td>

              <td>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
```

this my database

[image]

Comment: Use array_keys()[0] for that dynamic key.

Comment: @nice_dev i am getting the the (email,id,name,phone)vaule but I couldn't get the values of **car_details**......

Comment: Can you just var_export() your array and paste it in your question?

Comment: @nice_dev var_export() which array.. I didn't get it ??

Comment: Paste `var_export($fetchdata)` in your question.

Comment: That path or what you're attempting to read from that path is incorrect. The `.child('car_details')` path does not have child nodes of id, name, email etc. It only has child nodes of car_color, car_model etc. i.e. you can't read `car_details` from *inside* the `car_details` node. You would have to read that from the `0bwVPet...` node. By the way, in the future, please post Realtime Database structures as *text* so we can use them in answers with copy/paste.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user has a typo pointing to the wrong node they are trying to read.